# Configure SSIS logging to log in one file

Tags: ssis

I know configuring the logging for individual packages thru BIDS. But the drawback I see here is I have to add connectionstring for each tasks and when I have to deplloy these packages on server I have to change log file connectionstring for all packages. Currently I have 32 pacakes and this seems to be time consuming. 
Is there any way where I can set up logging for all packages in one place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at storing your configuration in either files or sql tables.  For instance, in my current project, I have a common configuration file that has all of the items (like logging that are common to the entire project, then I have individual config files for items that are different per package (like individual database connection strings and variables).  This allows me to modify the config on deployment without changing the package. SSIS reads in the configuration at runtime.  To use logging see the answers in this question:
[Is there a way to easily change the server name on several SSIS packages programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196012/is-there-a-way-to-easily-change-the-server-name-on-several-ssis-packages-programm/2196102#2196102)

Answer (score 0):

I run some jobs through the `DTEXEC` dos command and I redirect the output to a .log file.

Example

```
DTEXEC 
   /DTS "\File System\Customer_pkg" 
   /SERVER xxxxx 
   /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " 
   /CHECKPOINTING OFF  
   /REPORTING V > c:\log\Customer_pkg.log
```